# Ignoring a malformed part of a JSON object while parsing it, in Julia

Tags: json, parsing, julia

I have the following JSON string in my DataFrame

```
{\"id\": 312, \"type\": \"Symbol\", \"children\": {\"right\": {\"id\": 313, \"type\": \"BinaryOperation\", \"children\": {\"right\": {\"id\": 314, \"type\": \"Fraction\", \"children\": {\"right\": {\"id\": 317, \"type\": \"Brackets\", \"children\": {\"argument\": {\"id\": 318, \"type\": \"Fn\", \"children\": {\"right\": {\"id\": 320, \"type\": \"BinaryOperation\", \"children\": {\"right\": {\"id\": 321, \"type\": \"Num\", \"properties\": {\"significand\": \"1\"}}}, \"properties\": {\"operation\": \"+\"}}, \"argument\": {\"id\": 319, \"type\": \"Symbol\", \"properties\": {\"letter\": \"x\"}}}, \"properties\": {\"name\": \"ln\", \"allowSubscript\": false}}}, \"properties\": {\"type\": \"round\"}}, \"numerator\": {\"id\": 315, \"type\": \"Num\", \"properties\": {\"significand\": \"1\"}}, \"denominator\": {\"id\": 316, \"type\": \"Symbol\", \"properties\": {\"letter\": \"x\"}}}}}, \"properties\": {\"operation\": \"−\"}}}, \"position\": {\"x\": 114.97000305175781, \"y\": 231}, \"expression\": {\"latex\": \"k - \\frac{1}{x}\\left(\\ln(x) + 1\\right)\", \"python\": \"k - (1)/(x) * (ln(x) + 1)\"}, \"properties\": {\"letter\": \"k\"}}
```

Any parser will choke on `.expression.latex` because of the escaped slashes. Apparently, `\f` and `\r` are fine, but there needs to be an escaped slash in front of an `l`, thus that string for key `latex` should read more like

```
\"k - \\frac{1}{x}\\\\left(\\\\ln(x) + 1\\right)\"
```

which `JSON.parse` now parses fine. Now, I could simply replace an escaped `l` with one with more escaping (`\\\l`) but in practice I don't even need to parse that part of the object at all, that is, I can drop the `expression` key entirely. Is there a way of catching the error and telling the parser that it's OK to drop it and go ahead with the rest, or should I just suck it up and add extra escaping?

Comment: are you sure that `\r` and `\f` are not fine just because they are [C's traditional escaped input forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Backslash_escapes) ? See also [doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/strings/#man-characters-1)

Comment: btw. how do you get your json string? copy+paste to editor?

Comment: Query to a PostgreSQL db which includes json blobs, exported to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no escaped values in the JSON string replacing the backslashes with escaped backslashes can bring the string to a parsable format. Try:

```
using JSON
unescaped = ".... <string from question> ...."
escaped = replace(unescaped, "\\", "\\\\")
JSON.Parser.parse(escaped)
```

Giving:

```
Dict{String,Any} with 6 entries:
  "expression" => Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("latex", "k - \\frac{1}{x}\\left(\\ln(x) + 1\\right)"),Pair{String,Any}("pyt…
  "properties" => Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("letter", "k"))
  "id"         => 312
  "position"   => Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("x", 114.97),Pair{String,Any}("y", 231))
  "type"       => "Symbol"
  "children"   => Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("right", Dict{String,Any}(Pair{String,Any}("properties", Dict{String,Any}(Pa…
```

**Update**

Perhaps a better solution would be to target the replacement to just the `latex` field in `expression` in the following way (assuming it is the only source of trouble and there are no problems like the comments mentions):

```
newjson = replace(json, r"\"latex\": \"([^\"]*)\"", s -> replace(s,"\\","\\\\"))
```

**Update 2**

The problem arises because `JSON.Parser.parse` handles escaping, while LaTeX can accidentally introduce these escape sequences. As suggested by Liso in the comments:

```
escaped = replace(unescaped, r"\\([^\"\\/bfnrt])", s"\\\\\1")
```

would escape the backslash in the unescaped string and thus avoid unnecessary handling by `JSON.Parser.parse`. Note the list of escaped characters is in a dictionary accessible as `JSON.Common.ESCAPES`.

Comment: This `unescaped = JSON.Writer.json(Dict("latex"=>"k - \frac..."))` create unescaped similar to yours and your recipe is working fine. But try to simulate unescaped data with backslash or doublequote inside text! (for example:  `unescaped = JSON.Writer.json(Dict("latex"=>"k - \\ \" \frac..."))` )  I am afraid that source data in PostgreSQL or csv are really malformed. As first unescaped in this comment has to be: ` JSON.Writer.json(Dict("latex"=>"k -  \\frac..."))` (see double-backslash). We need "unmalform" function which is impossible if we don't know precisely what malformation appears here.

Comment: Probably something like this: `escaped = replace(unescaped, r"\\([^\"\\/bfnrt])", s"\\\\\1")` could avoid `ERROR: Invalid escape sequence`.

Comment: @Liso The JSON is malformed. The question is how best to handle it for this special case. I've updated the answer with a more targeted solution.

Comment: Yes. I think we are both just offering a non ideal solution. My second comment is just trying to eliminate the problem with `JSON.Common.ESCAPES` used in `JSON.Parser.parse_string` in `JSON/src/Parser.jl` ...

Comment: I'm not sure why but I ended up having to use eight back-slashes as replacement, something like `replace(unescaped, "\\", "\\\\\\\\")`. Good point about only targeting the latex portion, I could also use that to just get rid of it, since in practice I don't need it.